# Making html body large enough for content inside

Tags: html, css, styling

I'm working on a website for a side-project currently, but I don't have a lot of experience with web development. I've been tearing my hair out for the last hour trying to figure out why my page's `<body>` element is only rendering as tall as my viewport, rather than being tall enough to contain the content inside it. The result is that when I scroll down the page, the table that's inside the body overflows vertically and the body's black background visibly ends before the content inside it. Here is my CSS for the body:

```
html 
{ 
    background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
body
{
    width: 80%;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I'm not able to post an image unfortunately, but being able to see where the black content background ends is not particularly good-looking.

Comment: Is "the black background" referring to that image? If so, then you will have to repeat it as suggested by Samleo.

Comment: (http://imgur.com/ooKqW7q) Here's a screenshot of the bottom of the body. The background of the page is an image, but the background of the <body> is just transparent black. The circled parts in my linked image are the places where you can see the bottom of the black <body>, because it ends before the tables do.

Comment: That looks more weird than I thot. Maybe more code would help.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your body:

```
height: auto;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not working, the body still cuts off when I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
html{
   background: url(../images/background.jpg) repeat center center fixed; 
   height:100%;
}
```

Using

```
body{
   height:100%;
}
```

may not be good enough because that will be relative to the html which is not 100%;

**EDIT:** To answer your scroll part, you have to add in `background:repeat`.

Comment: Adding this made the body marginally taller (it had been coming up a few pixels short of the height of my viewport before, now it reaches the very bottom), but when I scroll down at all the background still stops.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the scrolling part earlier. setting background repeat should fix your problem

Comment: Can I specify the repeat on the body background when I use rgba()? I changed the line in my CSS inside the body{} block to: background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) repeat; but I still see no change. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I don't really understand what exactly you are aiming to achieve with this code... If you are looking for a simple black background with opacity 75% (0.75), then there is no need for repeat since a coloured background in CSS automatically "repeats".
<br>
However, if you are looking for making the background picture have an opacity of 75%, you have to use another CSS code..

Comment: For a background with opacity 75%, you will either have to edit the background using photoshop and make it opacity 75% (cross browser friendly) or using CSS3: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this property on your body tag

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```